# Extract text matching pattern X after having searched for pattern Y (bash)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

In a bash script how would I be able to extract a text from an XML file that begins with abc ends with /abc which comes after a pattern that I need to look for?
Exemple of the input file:

```
<111>
<abc>
text
</abc>
<def>
text
</def>
</111>
<222>
<abc>
text to extract
</abc>
</222>
```

My goal would be to display "text to extract" indicating I'm looking for the pattern <222>.

Comment: If it's a valid XML file use a XML parser like xmlint or xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 1):

1. your xml example doesn't have root element?
2. `<111> <222>` are not valid xml tag names
3. if you are not sure your xml format is fixed, don't use regex to parse it
4. xpath would be the way to go

assume the 111,222 tag named as `t111`, `t222` and you had a root element.

```
xmllint --xpath "//t222/abc/text()" your.xml
```

Comment: @John:  if you don't know the tag after t222 and you want to get rid of the newline: `xmllint --xpath "//t222/*/text()" your.xml | grep .`

Answer (score 0):

This is really ugly and you really should use @Kent's answer, but if you really, really insist:

```
grep -A 999 "<222>" file.xml | grep -A1 "<abc>" | tail -n 1
```

It takes up to 999 lines after finding your pattern `<222>`, and then, from that, it takes the single line following `<abc>` and from that it takes the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS and gensub():

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{print gensub(/.*<222>.*<abc>\n(.*)\n<\/abc>.*/,"\\1","")}' file
text to extract
```